# ASP MVC JavaScript ActionLink multiple replace?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I want to build a Url.Action link and pass parameters and I found an example here on stackoverflow that shows how to replace the value:

> var url = "@Url.Action("Export", "UserCalendar",new { from =
>   "_date", to="_to", groupId="_groupId" })".replace("_date",
>   _pdfExportStartDate);

How do I also replace _to and _groupId ? I tried

> url = url.replace("_to",_pdfExportEndDate)

after the first replace call and although it makes the correct URL string the value (_to) is never passed to the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add the querystring params to the base url (the one without any route values) as needed.

```
var _pdfExportStartDate = "11/11/2013";
var _toDate = "11/11/2013";

var baseUrl = "@Url.Action("Export", "UserCalendar")";
url = baseUrl +"?from = "+_pdfExportStartDate +"&to= "+ _toDate;
```